# DataContract class for Facebook 'Like' Graph API

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, datacontract, json

So I'm trying to decode the json returned by the Facebook Graph API for user likes into objects using the DataContractJsonSerializer.  I've tried creating a couple different [DataContract] classes now but with no luck.

What is the correct way to create a [DataContract] class for this data.

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Earlyups",
         "category": "Recreation/sports",
         "id": "170410902986097",
         "created_time": "2012-04-09T03:34:11+0000"
      },
      {
         "name": "pictureline inc.",
         "category": "Local business",
         "id": "28861182380",
         "created_time": "2012-03-28T02:02:24+0000"
      },
      {
         "name": "Jackson Hole Mountain Resort",
         "category": "Sports/recreation/activities",
         "id": "24718308041",
         "created_time": "2012-03-20T16:10:45+0000"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "next": "next_page_request_url"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haha, wow as soon as I posted I saw what I was doing wrong. In case anyone else is interested.

```
[DataContract]
        internal class LikePage
        {
            [DataMember]
            internal Like[] data;

            [DataMember]
            internal Paging paging;

        }

        [DataContract]
        internal class Like
        {
            [DataMember]
            internal string name;

            [DataMember]
            internal string category;

            [DataMember]
            internal string id;

            [DataMember]
            internal string created_time;
        }


        [DataContract]
        internal class Paging
        {
            [DataMember]
            internal string next;

        }
```